# Masonry grid with CSS using the :nth-child pseudo-selector?

Tags: jquery, css, grid, css-selectors

I'm trying to create a masonry grid using `:nth-child` in CSS, but it doesnt seems to work correctly....

My idea would be to have the first li item 33% width, second one 66% width - both align,

in the second row, first item 66% width, second li item 33% width - both align,

Fifth item come in the third row 100% width.

Then all repeat in the same order as I Just explained.

When I'm using this css:

```
  ul#comissions li:nth-child(4n-7){width:33%}
 { 
    width:33%
}
```

It should select  every fourth li item,

However it select every second li item . . .

Do you have any idea why ?

Here is a part of how my html is looking:

```
<section class="blog-list">
<ul id="comissions">

<li>


 <article class="entry cf hentry author-sinead-mccarthy post-type-text article-index-1" id="article-566586c6e4b00229eb49e5f7" data-item-id="566586c6e4b00229eb49e5f7">

     <div class="main-image-wrapper">

         <img src="myimg">
         fergerhgerh
     </div>
 </article>
 </li>
 <li>


  <article class="entry cf hentry author-sinead-mccarthy post-type-text article-index-1" id="article-566586c6e4b00229eb49e5f7" data-item-id="566586c6e4b00229eb49e5f7">

     <div class="main-image-wrapper">

         <img src="myimg">
         fergerhgerh
     </div>
</article>
 </li>
 <li>


   <article class="entry cf hentry author-sinead-mccarthy post-type-text article-index-1" id="article-566586c6e4b00229eb49e5f7" data-item-id="566586c6e4b00229eb49e5f7">

     <div class="main-image-wrapper">

         <img src="myimg">
         fergerhgerh
     </div>
</article>
 </li>
  <li>


    <article class="entry cf hentry author-sinead-mccarthy post-type-text article-index-1" id="article-566586c6e4b00229eb49e5f7" data-item-id="566586c6e4b00229eb49e5f7">

     <div class="main-image-wrapper">

         <img src="myimg">
         fergerhgerh
     </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this?

Comment: hmm - the thing is this the html output of my cms . . .I'm using square space - quite limited I do know 

I'll try to make a fiddle of it shortly, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u94nkvpL/)

Your css could be something like this:

```
ul#comissions li:nth-child(5n-4),
ul#comissions li:nth-child(5n-1){
  width: 33%
}
ul#comissions li:nth-child(5n-3),
ul#comissions li:nth-child(5n-2){
  width: 66%
}
ul#comissions li:nth-child(5n-0){
  width: 100%
}
```